# how to ignor(bypass) an ssh error in ssh bash command and continue the command?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

ex:

```
cd /var/www && cd /doesNotExist && cd /var
```

will generate an error and stops the command and thus will not go to /var

Is there a way to prevent that (and so ignor an error in command) ?
(not only for the cd command but for ANY ssh command)

regards

Comment: How is SSH involved in this question?

Answer (score 2):

Use `||` instead:

```
cd /var/www || cd /doesNotExist || cd /var
```

Which would only allow changing to other directories if error occurred on the first ones.

Optionally you can suppress error messages:

```
{ cd /var/www || cd /doesNotExist || cd /var; } >/dev/null 2>&1
```

If you want commands to work in a single line regardless if there was an error or not on the preceding commands, just use a semicolon:

```
cd /var/www; cd /doesNotExist; cd /var
```